# Chromedriver will automatically quit

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, web-crawler

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome("D:/visualStudioWorkspace/crawling/chromedriver.exe")
browser.maximize_window()

url = "https://flight.naver.com/"
browser.get(url)
```

when the program is over, chrome driver will automatically quit

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70498853/keeping-selenium-browser-open-after-python-script-completion

Comment: You can put in a breakpoint to keep the browser open: ``import pdb; pdb.set_trace()``

Comment: What else do you expect to happen ? there's no code and that's why it's getting automatically closed.